# ApplicationId and ConfigurationProfileId in CreateHostedConfigurationVersion

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, app-config

I need to create a new version of appConfig from node.js
I know about CreateHostedConfigurationVersion method from appconfige AWS
But I didn't know from where I need to bring parameteres such as ApplicationId and ConfigurationProfileId.
I only have Application, ClientId, Configuration and Env.